# What is the problem in this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, function, iframe

```
var urlname= '/a/b.php?company_name='+company_name+'&series='+series;
document.getElementById('frame2').innerHTML='<IFRAME HEIGHT="600px" WIDTH="100%" NORESIZE="NORESIZE" SRC="'+urlname+'" NAME="aol" FRAMEBORDER="0" ALIGN="ABSBOTTOM" scrolling="no" id="a1" name="a1" onload="Javascript:heights('a1')"></IFRAME>';
```

I'm using this code but the function heights() is not running and it's not showing any error too. What's the right syntax to call a function with arguments in JavaScript. I'm new to it so don't have much idea. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Firefox/Firebug to debug? What happens if you navigate directly to the url used in the iframe src? Does the function run?

Comment: see the function heights() is used for auto adjusting the height of my iframe.This should auto set the height which it is not doing.thats why im stuck.

Comment: "Javascript:" is useless in an event handler attribute such as onload. You've confused it with the "javascript:" pseudo-protocol in the href attribute of an <a> element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the heights function located?

You need to escape the most inner quotes and remove "javascript:", eg replace `onload="Javascript:heights('a1')"` with `onload="heights(\'a1\')"`

Comment: i tried it before but it didnt worked(dont know why when it should have worked) but when i tried it again now after reading your posts it seems working to me :-)

Comment: Where is the heights function?

Answer (score 1):

Adding strings together is not as easy as you think. You've got all sorts of problems here.

> var urlname= '/a/b.php?company_name='+company_name+'&series='+series;

If company_name and series can have characters in that can't go in a URL parameter, like spaces or pluses or percents or ampersands or Unicode, this breaks. They need encoding.

> innerHTML='<IFRAME HEIGHT="600px" WIDTH="100%" NORESIZE="NORESIZE"

You can't use 'px' units in HTML, that's CSS. noresize isn't needed, you can't resize iframes anyway.

> SRC="'+urlname+'"

If urlname contains ", < or & you might have trouble. Needs to be HTML-encoded.

> NAME="aol" FRAMEBORDER="0" ALIGN="ABSBOTTOM" scrolling="no" id="a1" name="a1"

You've got two names? That's invalid and will confuse anything trying to use the window.frames array or getElementsByName.

> onload="Javascript:heights('a1')">

' needs backslash-escaping since you used that as the string delimiter in your innerHTML='...' assignment.

Don't begin an event handler with 'javascript:', that only makes sense in an href (and even then, javascript: URLs should never be used).

If you make your heights() function take an object instead of an id string, you can do away with all those names. And using DOM methods lets you avoid thinking about HTML-escaping. eg.:

```
function heights() {
    alert(this.offsetHeight); // 'this' is the object the event was called on
}

var iframe= document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.frameBorder=iframe.scrolling= 'no';
iframe.style.height= '600px';
iframe.style.width= '100%';
iframe.onload= heights;
iframe.src= '/a/b.php?company_name='+encodeURIComponent(company_name)+'&series='+encodeURIComponent(series);
document.getElementById('frame2').appendChild(iframe);
```

Answer (score 0):

check out with the url path you are given. try like this.

```
var urlname= './a/b.php?company_name='+company_name+'&series='+series;
```

And also escape the quotes

```
Javascript:heights(\'a1\')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JavaScript:heights onload="" is already scoped to execute JavaScript. You can try it with this: onload="alert('hello world')"